# Django makemessages "struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 4 bytes"

Tags: python, django, docker, gettext, makemessages

I have a django instance packed in Docker container in docker-compose.

I'm trying to generate makemessages files for project, but when I try to run makemessages, that's what I receieve in response

```
root@6fc510c9c5d1:/code# python manage.py makemessages
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/daphne/server.py:12: UserWarning: Something has already installed a non-asyncio Twisted reactor. Attempting to uninstall it; you can fix this warning by importing daphne.server early in your codebase or finding the package that imports Twisted and importing it later on.
  UserWarning,
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 347, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 112, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 94, in <module>
    class Group(models.Model):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 152, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class(obj_name, obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 315, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 1586, in contribute_to_class
    self.remote_field.through = create_many_to_many_intermediary_model(self, cls)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 1051, in create_many_to_many_intermediary_model
    'verbose_name': _('%(from)s-%(to)s relationship') % {'from': from_, 'to': to},
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 148, in __mod__
    return str(self) % rhs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 112, in __text_cast
    return func(*self.__args, **self.__kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 77, in gettext
    return _trans.gettext(message)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 312, in gettext
    _default = _default or translation(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 221, in translation
    _translations[language] = DjangoTranslation(language)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 122, in __init__
    self._add_installed_apps_translations()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 170, in _add_installed_apps_translations
    translation = self._new_gnu_trans(localedir)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 149, in _new_gnu_trans
    fallback=use_null_fallback)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/gettext.py", line 538, in translation
    t = _translations.setdefault(key, class_(fp))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/gettext.py", line 254, in __init__
    self._parse(fp)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/gettext.py", line 345, in _parse
    magic = unpack('<I', buf[:4])[0]
struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 4 bytes
```

Do you have any ideas what it can be?

Comment: Your problem is at this line: `magic = unpack('<I', buf[:4])[0]` with this error: `struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 4 bytes`

Comment: Can you put on your relevent snippet code with the mentioned error here?

Answer (score 9):

It might be raised by your .mo file(s). Please check if this file is empty.
If this is indeed the case. Remove your .mo file and rerun the `makemessages` command.

It should solve the issue you're having.

If this doesn't solve your issue. Try this:

1. Save all the .po files in a different location (create a backup of your locale file)
2. delete all the languages in locale folder.
3. Rerun the command

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was because I had errors on the `django-admin makemessages` command. I had a `msgstr ""` missing and it was propted as a fatal error, once I added it the `django.mo` file got filled and everything worked fine.